# my javascript code with classList.toggle doesn't work well

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

i made a button that makes my div hide and visible.
It works well once or twice but and then It doesn't
(I click the button with column1
doesn't open the column 1's hidden div
then I click the column2
column2's hidden div is opening....)

sorry for my bad english but I really wanna know why

```js
var tabList = document.querySelectorAll("li");

tabList.forEach(function(tab, index) {
  tab.addEventListener('click', function() {
    removeOther();
    tab.classList.toggle("on");
    btnEvent(tab);
  });
});

function removeOther() {
  for (var i = 0; i < tabList.length; i++) {
    if (tabList[i].classList.contains("on")) {
      tabList[i].classList.remove("on");
    }
  }
}

var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

function btnEvent(tab) {
  var hiddenTabs = tab.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < hiddenTabs.length; i++) {
      hiddenTabs[i].classList.toggle("hidden");
    }
  })
}
```

```css
div {
  background: salmon;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: none;
}

div.hidden,
li.on div.hidden {
  display: none;
}

li.on div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="on">column1
    <div>box</div>
    <div>box</div>
    <div>box</div>
    <div class="hidden">box</div>
    <div class="hidden">box</div>
    <div class="hidden">box</div>
  </li>
  <li>column2
    <div>box</div>
    <div>box</div>
    <div>box</div>
    <div class="hidden">box</div>
    <div class="hidden">box</div>
    <div class="hidden">box</div>
  </li>
  <li>column3
    <div>box</div>
    <div>box</div>
    <div>box</div>
    <div class="hidden">box</div>
    <div class="hidden">box</div>
    <div class="hidden">box</div>
  </li>
</ul>
<button>click!</button>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do with `on` class?

Comment: You are adding a new click event on your <button> every time you click on a <li>. After two clicks on the same <li>, you'll toggle 'hidden' twice => no change on this <li>. If you click on an other <li> then next button click will still affect the previous <li> Change your logic so that you have only one event listener on your <button>

Comment: can you share the corresponding styles? `.on`  `.hidden`

Comment: sorry this is my style tag div{
      background:salmon;
      width:50px;
      height:50px;
      margin: 5px;
      display:none;
    }

    div.hidden, li.on div.hidden{
      display:none;
    }

    li.on div{
      display:block;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following JS codesnippet

```js
var tabList = document.querySelectorAll("li");

// move btn selector to the top of the script part 
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

tabList.forEach(function(tab, index) {
  tab.addEventListener('click', function() {
    removeOther();
    tab.classList.toggle("on");
    btnEvent(tab);
  });

  // initially run the click event on the first tab element
  if (index < 1) tab.click();
});

function removeOther() {
  for (var i = 0; i < tabList.length; i++) {
    if (tabList[i].classList.contains("on")) {
      tabList[i].classList.remove("on");
    }
  }
}

function btnEvent(tab) {

  // add .not-hidden, to mark .hidden elements, 
  var hiddenTabs = tab.querySelectorAll('.hidden,.not-hidden');

  // should be applied as onclick attribute
  // addEventListener adds a new Event at each time
  btn.onclick = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < hiddenTabs.length; i++) {
      hiddenTabs[i].classList.toggle("hidden");

      // toggle element class to .not-hidden while it is not hidden
      hiddenTabs[i].classList.toggle("not-hidden");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  background: salmon;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: none;
}

div.hidden,
li.on div.hidden {
  display: none;
}

li.on div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="on">column1
    <div>box</div>
    <div>box</div>
    <div>box</div>
    <div class="hidden">box</div>
    <div class="hidden">box</div>
    <div class="hidden">box</div>
  </li>
  <li>column2
    <div>box</div>
    <div>box</div>
    <div>box</div>
    <div class="hidden">box</div>
    <div class="hidden">box</div>
    <div class="hidden">box</div>
  </li>
  <li>column3
    <div>box</div>
    <div>box</div>
    <div>box</div>
    <div class="hidden">box</div>
    <div class="hidden">box</div>
    <div class="hidden">box</div>
  </li>
</ul>
<button>click!</button>
```